# jQuery toggle dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I want to toggle divs dynamically. Here is what I found so far...

```
$(".toggle").click(function() { 
$(this).next('.container').toggle('fast'); 
});
```

What I have is this (HTML):

```
<h4 class="toggle">1</h4>
<h4 class="toggle">2</h4>
<h4 class="toggle">3</h4>
<div class="container">Content1</div>
<div class="container">Content2</div>
<div class="container">Content3</div>
```

When I click the FIRST element (h4 with class toggle) I want the FIRST element with class container to open / close.

When I click the second toggle-class the second container-class should open.

The next in my example don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need/want to keep this DOM structure, you should use the `index`.

```
$('.toggle').click(function() {
    $('.container').eq($(this).index()).toggle('fast');
});
```

Ref.: [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/36/

Comment: Very nice, faster than me, and I didn't know you could use index() without arguments. +1 :)

Comment: Nice to include jsfiddle. Makes it easy to test and give you a green "check".

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is

```
$(".toggle").click(function() { 
    $($('.container')[$(this).index(".toggle")]).toggle('fast'); 
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/utPza/)

Answer (score 0):

You may try out the [toggle feature of JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/). And I will rather have some other dependency between the headers and the content divs, rather than trusting the order of their occurrence.

Answer (score -1):

if you change the order of your html:

```
<h4 class="toggle">1</h4>
<div class="container">Content1</div>
<h4 class="toggle">2</h4>
<div class="container">Content2</div>
<h4 class="toggle">3</h4>
<div class="container">Content3</div>
```

your code works, because it's just getting the next DOM element and toggling it if it matches the class. However it's pretty shaky and other people's examples that tell js more specifically what to do would be better.